# Map certain data to models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-3.0

Say I have a movie database. I want to map films of Quentin Tarantino to Quentin Tarantino. But given that Quentin only makes Historical Dramas (consider this a genre), I should only be able to map Historical Dramas to Quentin. How do I achieve this without creating a special model just for that genre? Consider you have a singular Genre model.

Comment: You need to be more specific. As it's formulated, it's hard to understand what you want. Show us your code and what specifically is not working. What does "map films of X to X" actually mean?

Comment: It's imho very clear. Director and Movie models with a ManyToMany relationship constrained by movie.genre==director.genre

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a custom constraint to the Director model:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q, Model, ManyToManyField, CharField

class Director(Model):
    movies = ManyToManyField(Movie)
    genre = CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(genre=F(genre)),
                name='correct_genre'
            )
        ]
```